# MongoDB shell find query

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell, mongodb-query

I am running a simple find query from unix shell.

```
mongo <<DB NAME>> -u <<USERNAME>> -p <<PASSWORD>> <<HOST>>:<<PORT>> --authenticationDatabase <<AUTHENTICATION DB NAME>> --eval db[<<COLLECTION NAME>>].find({"name":"Harsha"})
```

I am getting below error.

```
[js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:6
```

I also tried by changing DB name place (ex: `host:port/db_name`)

```
mongo -u <<USERNAME>> -p <<PASSWORD>> <<HOST>>:<<PORT>>/<<DB NAME>> --authenticationDatabase <<AUTHENTICATION DB NAME>> --eval db[<<COLLECTION NAME>>].find({"name":"Harsha"})
```

Still getting same error.

Am I missing something? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB expects the argument of `--eval` to be passed as string like in [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#eval-option) example:

```
--eval "db[<<COLLECTION NAME>>].find({'name':'Harsha'})"
```